# PHP Post Request with CURL - image + array

Tags: php, file, curl, post

I'm trying to post a multipart request to an API that contains both an image and an array that has details about that image. This request works via Postman but implementing it using CURL in PHP is proving difficult.

The headers are pretty basic - they just contain an $auth_token that is retrieved previously from other api calls.

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data', 'Authorization-token: ' . $auth_token));
```

The actual body of the form data is as follows - a CurlFile is instantiated as follows and an array with information about the file

```
$fields = array(
    "data" => new CurlFile('C://images/15.jpg', 'image/jpg', '15.jpg'),
    "entityFile" => array(
        "fileTypeID"=> "server generated id",
        "fileSize"=> 23453,
        "entityID"=> "another server generated id",
        "fileDateUtc"=> "2018-02-26T00:00:00",
        "fileName"=> "15",
        "fileExtension"=> "jpg"
    )
);
```

Finally I set options for the data to be sent

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

I have also tried attaching the image as a base64 encoded string but the image on the server is not changed.

My question is whether there is anything apparently wrong with my $fields array that might be causing it to fail? I suspect that there may be a problem with the actual file but it is hard to determine as the actual error returned is...

```
The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request
```

Thank you

Comment: there should be more information to the bad request, usually they will tell you the reason why. check thorougly on your response

Comment: Thank you - if I error_log(var_export($result, true)); I get that error. Is there anything else I can try to get more information?

Comment: if(curl_error($c))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($c);
}

This will give you the curl error. But also check in your developer tools (F12), at times the browser will output error messages at the top of the page

Comment: curl_error($c) and the dev tools (Chrome) give the same error

Comment: what API are you using? there is an error with the information you are sending  the API that is the reason you are getting 400.

Comment: The API used is basically unknown to the public and I am not authorised to post it here unfortunately.